# How to find bounds for $\phi$ in spherical coordinates with a cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates, bounds-of-integration

I have a sphere and a cone making up a region.

Sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}= a^{2}$
Cone $z=c \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

Where $c$ and $a$ are positive constants.

I need to find the integral of $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ over the region that is above the cone and below the sphere. Using spherical coordinates I have set up the following bounds:

$ 0 ≤ ρ ≤ a $

$ 0 ≤ θ ≤ 2\pi $

$0 ≤ φ ≤  ? $

I don't know how to find the bounds for phi. If there were no constants I would have plugged in

$x^{2}+y^{2}+{(c\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})}^{2} = a^{2}$
then

$ (c^{2} +1) (x^{2}+y^{2})= a^{2}$
then $x^{2}+y^{2} = r^{2} $
so $ (c^{2} +1) (r^2)= a^{2}$

$ r= \frac{a}{\sqrt{c^{2}+1}}$

we also know the relationship 
$ r= ρ\sin\phi$

So finally

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{c^{2}+1}} =\sin\phi$
Then I would take inverse sign which would give me the max angle for $φ$ and therefore would know the bound, in this case I don't know and I don't know how to find it, I was considering using cylindrical coordinates instead but it led to a tedious integral. Please your advice on how to solve this and the thought process behind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are given $$z=c\sqrt {x^2+y^2}= cr$$ and you know that $$\tan \phi = \frac {r}{z}$$

We get $$\tan \phi =1/c$$

Thus the limits for $\phi$ are $$0\le \phi \le \tan ^{-1} (1/c)$$

Comment: I agree with how you got the bounds however If I start with integrating with respect to $\phi$ I have to integrate $ρ^{4}sin\phi$ I get  $-ρ^{4}cos\phi$ then plugging in the bounds gives $-ρ^{4}cos(arctan(1/c))$ how does this then become an actual value in terms of c?

Comment: You know tangent is $1/c$ so you can find your cosine in terms of $c$ from $1+\tan ^2 x=\sec ^2 x$